# USB CDC device stalling

Tags: embedded, usb, avr, cdc

I'm writing a simple virtual serial port device to report an older serial port. By this point I'm able to enumerate the device and send/receive characters.

After a varying number of bulk-out transmissions from the host to the device the endpoint appears to give up and stop transferring data. On the PC side I receive a write error, and judging from a USBlyzer trace the music stops on a stall (USBD_STATUS_STALL_PID). However my code never intentionally issues a STALL condition on that endpoint and the status flag for having generated one never gets set though.

Given the short amount of time elapsed (<300 µs) between issuing the request and the STALL it would appear to be an invalid response of some sort, and not a time-out. On the device side the output endpoint is ready to go, with data in the buffer and proper DATA0/1 synchronization, but nothing further ever happens.

Note that the device appears to work fine even for long periods of time until I start sending "large" quantities of data. As near as I can tell the device enumeration/configuration also appears to complete successfully. Oh, and the bulk-in endpoint continues to work just fine after this.

For the record I'm using the standard Windows usbser.sys driver and an XMega128A4U µP. I'm also seeing the same behaviour across multiple Windows Vista and 7 machines.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong or what further tests I might run to narrow things down?

[USBlyzer log](https://sites.google.com/site/doynax/USB%20Test%20Run.html),
[USB CDC stack](https://sites.google.com/site/doynax/USB%20Test.c),
[test project](https://sites.google.com/site/doynax/USB%20Test.zip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record this eventually turned out to be an oscillator problem. (Apparently the FLL's reference is always 1,024 Hz even when the 1,000 Hz USB frames are chosen. The slight clock error meant that a packet occasionally got rejected if it happened to contain one too many 1-bits in a row.)

I guess the moral of the story is to check the basics before assuming you've got a problem with the higher-level protocol. Also in retrospect a hardware USB analyzer would have been a worthwhile investment, the software alternatives mostly seems to spit out a generic error code or nothing at all when something goes awry.

Answer (score 2):

Stalling the out-endpoint may happen on an overflow of the output buffer on the host side. Are you sure that the device does fetch the data it receives via out-endpoint - and if so does it fetch the data at least as fast as data is sent to the device?

> Note that the device appears to work fine even for long periods of
>   time until I start sending "large" quantities of data.

This seems to be a hint for an overflow of the output-buffer.

Comment: Oh, I though that there was a flow control mechanism based on regular NACKs for CDC devices. Any idea how the rate is limited then? If the USBlyzer log is to be believed then the device last fetched data ~30 ms before the stall.